# Copy code from Visual Studio to open office writer will lose format or spacing

Tags: visual-studio, format

I would like to copy and paste code.
I'm using visual studio 2015 and when I copy code to paste it in open office writter, if a keep it formatted there is no spacing. 
I have made the test using productivity power tool and not using it, the result is the same.
Do you have any advice ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For copying formatted code in `Visual Studio` you can use the corresponding version (`2015`, `2017`, etc.) of **[Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools)** extension and then Copy → Paste the code. For copying code as HTML use Edit → Copy Html Markup menu on `Visual Studio` as well.